# C# Preprocessor Directives in embedded text files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, embedded-resource, preprocessor-directive

I have an ASP MVC Web project with embedded `*.less` files (this is just a text). I would like to `@include` some other resources in `Debug` mode, but don't do it in `Release`. Is it possible to say a compiler use C# Preprocessor directives inside embedded text files?

I have no idea how can I do this, but it would be perfect if it is possible :)

```
#if Debug
  @include ('debug.less')
#else
  @include ('release.less')
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

C# has no support for `#include`, unfortunately, and `#if/#else/#endif` is only supported in CS files.

Comment: My `@include` is the LESS CSS operator (not C/C++). This is just an example of how I'm going to use it. Generally I would like to bring C# preprocessor instructions into embedded resource files. I could write my own code to support this option, but I would like to check that I'm not going to invent a wheel :) Thanks anyway

Comment: Maybe you should solve it with build configurations - I don't know the details of course, but that's where you can control the behaviour for debug and release mode.

Comment: Maybe T4 can be helpful here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx